# 'woocommerce_email_order_details' hook not returning order details in admin new order notification email

Tags: hook-woocommerce

I am using the standard unmodified 'New Order' template in WooCommerce. Astra theme and Elementor. The EMail is being sent correctly, but does not include order line items although the rest of the Email is formatted correctly. See image.

Pretty sure it hasn't worked since installation. How should I fault find?

```
/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

[New Order Without Order Detail Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFsIF.png)

Comment: do you have a plugin customizing the emails? have you check the email-order-details.php for issues?

Comment: No plugins customizing emails installed.